# Insert and update in single stored procedure not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

When a user updates his profile picture, I want to insert it into a table and update just two columns in another table. It works fine for just one entry and stopped updating 2nd table.. don't know what is the error

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UploadProfilePic]
     (@UserName Nvarchar(50),
      @ImageName Nvarchar(max),
      @OrgImageName Nvarchar(max),
      @CommentImage Nvarchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Username FROM ProfilePic WHERE UserName = @UserName)
    Begin
          insert into ProfilePic ([UserName], [ImageName], [OrgImageName], [IsActive], [CommentImage])
          values(@UserName, @ImageName, @OrgImageName, 'Y', @CommentImage)

          Update UserProfile 
          set ProfileImg = @ImageName,
              PostImage = @CommentImage
          where UserName = @UserName
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       UPDATE ProfilePic 
       SET IsActive = 'N' 
       WHERE UserName = @UserName

       INSERT INTO ProfilePic ([UserName], [ImageName], [OrgImageName], [IsActive],[CommentImage])
       VALUES(@UserName, @ImageName, @OrgImageName, 'Y', @CommentImage)
   END
END
```

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag because of the `@` for variables, and the `nvarchar(max)` datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I have created a fiddle, check this please:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73aff0/6

I think that the issue was that you missed to add the update statement in the else case, so for new users it has been working - but not for the ones who were already existing.

```
    BEGIN
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Username FROM ProfilePic WHERE UserName = @UserName)
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO ProfilePic ([UserName], [ImageName], [OrgImageName], [IsActive],     [CommentImage])
          VALUES (@UserName, @ImageName, @OrgImageName, 'Y', @CommentImage)

          UPDATE UserProfile 
          SET ProfileImg = @ImageName,
              PostImage = @CommentImage
          WHERE UserName = @UserName
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
           UPDATE ProfilePic 
           SET IsActive = 'N' 
           WHERE UserName = @UserName

           INSERT INTO ProfilePic ([UserName], [ImageName], [OrgImageName], [IsActive],    [CommentImage])
           VALUES(@UserName, @ImageName, @OrgImageName, 'Y', @CommentImage)

           UPDATE UserProfile 
           SET ProfileImg = @ImageName,
               PostImage = @CommentImage
           WHERE UserName = @UserName
       END
    END
```

Comment: this is a poor approach you have wrapped the else part in a separate transaction, this whole statement `IF..ELSE` should be in one transaction. Also OP's method is fine as it is, I think the issue is with data somewhere.

Comment: @M.Ali - thanks, could you please tell me in a few words why is it a poor approach? Is it slow, heavy load?

Comment: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1..... i got this error after the change

Comment: @M.Ali if its poor approach what is the best way to do it... please help me in this friends.. and there no issue with data it worker fine until i set update to second table and also worked for the first attempt of update to second table but then after it became just silent in updating second table

Comment: @Alex thank you very much its working.......... but why it dint worked earlier... is it just because of difference in if and else statements??

Comment: @kumar - glad that it's working! The issue was, that as you have set it up, it looks at two scenarios: Does the user already exist? Yes or no. In your original query, you have only updated UserProfile table's value if the user **did not** exist, and you didn't update it, if it was an already existing user. I have only added the latter to your code after being able to reproduce your issue. Hope this makes sense and happy coding ;)

Comment: A better approach is to 1. Gather all pertinent data into temp tables. 2. Make decision (set variables) based on data in temp table 3. Modify temp tables 4. Update or Insert into database from temp tables inside a transaction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592038/update-a-table-from-a-temp-table

Answer (score 0):

Your question actually brings up a very interesting and very common situation. Here is one technique to use merge to address this scenario. This is not exactly and precisely what was asked for as I have modified the schema and moved some bits about, but it's a good example of how to address this scenario.

```
--
-------------------------------------------------
if schema_id(N'profile') is null
  execute (N'create schema profile');
go
if object_id(N'[profile].[picture]', N'U') is not null
  drop table [profile].[picture];
go
if object_id(N'[profile].[user]', N'U') is not null
  drop table [profile].[user];
go
create table [profile].[user]
  (
     [id]          [int] not null identity(1, 1) constraint [profile.user.id.clustered_primary_key] primary key clustered
     , [user_name] [sysname]
  );
go
create table [profile].[picture]
  (
     [id]              [int] not null identity(1, 1) constraint [profile.picture.id.clustered_primary_key] primary key clustered
     , [image_name]    [sysname]
     , [image_comment] [nvarchar](max)
     , [is_active]     [bit]
     , [user]          [int] constraint [profile.picture.user] references [profile].[user] ([id])
  );
go
--
if object_id(N'[profile].[set_picture]', N'P') is not null
  drop procedure [profile].[set_picture];
go
create procedure [profile].[set_picture]
  @user_id         [int]
  , @image_name    [nvarchar](max)
  , @image_comment [nvarchar](max)
as
  begin
      declare @output table
        (
           [action] [sysname]
           , [id]   [int]
        );
      --
      merge into [profile].[picture] as target
      using (values(@user_id
            , @image_name
            , @image_comment)) as source ([user], [image_name], [image_comment])
      on source.[user] = target.[user]
         and source.[image_name] = target.[image_name]
      when matched then
        update set target.[is_active] = 1
                   , target.[image_name] = source.[image_name]
                   , target.[image_comment] = source.[image_comment]
      when not matched by target then
        insert ([user]
                , [image_name]
                , [image_comment]
                , [is_active])
        values ([user]
                , [image_name]
                , [image_comment]
                , 0)
      output $action
             , coalesce(inserted.[id], deleted.[id])
      into @output([action], [id]);
  end;
go
--
-- note that you cannot insert a picture for a user that doesn't exist
-------------------------------------------------
insert into [profile].[user]
            ([user_name])
     values (N'sally'),
            (N'kevin');
go
select *
  from [profile].[user];
--
-- and the first insert gets an [is_active] value of 0
-- so you set it a second time to activate it
-------------------------------------------------
execute [profile].[set_picture]
  @user_id         =1
  , @image_name    =N'at the park'
  , @image_comment =N'she looks good in that dress';
go
execute [profile].[set_picture]
  @user_id         =1
  , @image_name    =N'at church'
  , @image_comment =N'but I like the blue dress better';
go
--
-------------------------------------------------
execute [profile].[set_picture]
  @user_id         =2
  , @image_name    =N'at work'
  , @image_comment =N'nice smile';
go
execute [profile].[set_picture]
  @user_id         =2
  , @image_name    =N'at work'
  , @image_comment =N'nice smile';
go
--
-------------------------------------------------
select *
  from [profile].[picture];
go
--
```